# function to remove/delete template from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom, button

I've been working on this for a few hours and I can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to get this function to remove the template when the button is clicked

here is the html of the template.

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/template">
        <div class="row my-3 t-3 card-movie ">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                <div class="card border-0 shadow">
                    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/400?img=48" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <h5 class="card-title mb-0">Title in Template</h5>
                        <div class="card-genre text-black-50">Genre in Template</div>
                        <div class="card-year text-black-50">Year in Template</div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteMovie mt-2">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is the function calling that button

```
function wireHandlers() {
            $(".deleteMovie").on("click", onDeleteMovie);
        };
```

and finally the function that should delete the template

```
function onDeleteMovie() {

            $(".card-movie").remove();
        };
```

I know there is probably a shorthand way to do this but I would really like to keep it as simple as possible. Any help is appriciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could call `click` directly on the button:

```
$( ".deleteMovie" ).click(function() {
  $(".card-movie").remove();
});
```

This method is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`

Documentation for the same is [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

You did not attached event because you not executed `wireHandlers()`

Your `class` selector was wrong `.delete-movie`

You have to attach event when document loads. More easy way to do is:

```js
$(document).on("click",".deleteMovie", function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row my-3 t-3 card-movie ">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
            <div class="card border-0 shadow">
                <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/400?img=48" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-0">Title in Template</h5>
                    <div class="card-genre text-black-50">Genre in Template</div>
                    <div class="card-year text-black-50">Year in Template</div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteMovie mt-2">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is best way when data is dynamically added:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
```